# Find orthogonal projection matrix $P$ of rank $r$ which maximizes $\mathbb E_x\left[\frac{\|Px\|}{\|x\|}\right]$

Tags: probability, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, matrix-norms

Let $x$ be a random vector in on the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^p$ with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Let $r \in \{1,2,\ldots,p\}$.

> **Question.** Find an orthogonal projection matrix $P \in \mathbb R^{p \times p}$ of rank $r$ which maximizes $\mathbb E_x\left[\|Px\|\right]$.

**Notes.** I have a strong feeling the the singular-value decomposition of $\Sigma$ has a role to play here...

---

## Edit: solution for modified objective: $E_x[\|Px\|^2]$

As kindly pointed out by J.G in the comments, modifying the objective to $E_x[\|Px\|^2]$ might lead to a easier problem.

Indeed,

$$
\arg\max_P E_x\|Px\|^2 = \arg\max_P \text{trace}(P\Sigma) + \mu^T\Sigma\mu = \arg\max_P \text{trace}(P\Sigma),
\tag{1}
$$

which is a linear-programming problem on the space of orthogonal matrices of rank $r$. Most importantly, the solution problem only depends on the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ of the random variable $x$.

As for an analytic solution of problem (1), one recognizes this problem an instance of *principal component analysis (PCA)*, and can be solved by taking $P = V_rV_r^T$, where $V_r \in \mathbb R^{p \times r}$ is the matrix whose columns are the leading $r$ eigenvectors (normalized to have unit norm) of $\Sigma$.

Comment: I don't think that the information are enough to come up with a unique solution. Notice that the mean and the covariance matrix do not identify $x$

Comment: Ah sorry for the misunderstanding. I didn't mean **unique** solution, but any solution. See updated text.

Comment: Would you be happy with maximizing the expected square norm? It’s technically a different problem but I think that one has an easy solution.

Comment: Yes, now that I think of it, the expected square would give: $E||Px||^2 = trace(P^TP\Sigma) + \mu^T\Sigma\mu$. Which is indeed an easy problem in $P$. Ah, i posted the question here kind of in a hurry. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: @J.G I just wrote down a solution (as an edit to the question). It boils down to taking the $P$ to be the orthgonal projection matrix onto the subspace spanned by $r$ leading eigenvectors of the covariance matrix.

Comment: @dohmatob how did you get that? shouldn't it be $\mathbf{1}^T(\Sigma\odot (P^TP))\mathbf{1}$?

Comment: It is a well-known formula (e.g see matric cookbook) that $E_x\|Ax\|^2 = trace(A^TA\Sigma) + \mu^T\Sigma\mu$. In my case, $A=P$ (an orthgonal projection matrix), and so $A^TA = P^TP = P^2 = P$.

Answer (score 1):

Take for example $x$ to be a vector of 2 iid Gaussian variables with mean 0 and variance 1. If you take $r=1$, then any projection gives you the same average, since you can orthogonally base change to a fixed projection.

Now let $x$ be a vector of 2 independent random variables, where the first is a zero-norm unit-variance Gaussian random variable, and the second is a discrete random variable with mean zero and unit variance (that is, it takes values in {1,-1} with probability 1/2). 
Now the projections to each coordinate give different expectations.

Comment: Ah you posted your answer while I was updating the question to make things clearer. In particular, note that the issue is not **uniqueness**. I'm interested in **any** solution.

Comment: @dohmatob the problem here is another

Comment: @dohmatob the solution cannot depend only on mean and covariance matrix

Comment: Ah, ok i didn't read your answer in detail, just your comment to the question. Indeed, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: Let's forget about mean and covariance. I'd be interested in a solution which depends on other statistics of $x$.

Comment: The idea would be to estimate a approximate solution $\hat{P}$ based on $n$ iid samples, and then hope that this solution depends smoothly on some population-wise statistics of $x$, and then let the "delta metho"d kick-in. But then, this takes us far from the original question perhaps...